# What is the solution to this metapuzzle from a university puzzling column?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, metapuzzles

### The puzzle

**Title:** Italy is Divine

**Content:**

> Flowers and spring
> Fresh water and the sea
> Hearth and home
> Grain and agriculture

**Answers from the last four puzzles:** (spoilered in case you want to solve them yourself)

> FORMAL
>  NEATEN UP
>  STARVE
>  RECESS

---

### Context

UC Berkeley (my current university) had a [Campus League of Puzzlers](https://puzzle.berkeley.edu/main/home/) that produced a column in the campus newspaper called Fiat Enigma. In recent years, the League has been inactive, almos non-existent, and the Spring 2016 edition of Fiat Enigma was their last one as of the creation of this post. The last puzzle of this set, Puzzle 14, was a metapuzzle that used the answers to the previous four puzzles, Puzzles 10-13. You can view the original pdf of this puzzle as well as the others from the column [here](https://puzzle.berkeley.edu/main/column/).

While almost every puzzle in the column has had their solution published, I have not found a solution to this one posted anywhere on their website, nor have I found any information through Googling. So now my question is simply this: **what is the solution to Fiat Enigma's Spring 2016 metapuzzle?** I'm looking for a full solution if possible (either through directly solving or searching it up), but partial answers are also welcome.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The answer is

> MARS

obtained by

> removing from each of the previous four answers the letters making the name of a Roman deity -- of flowers and spring (FLORA) for the first one (FORMAL), etc. The deities' names, in order, are: Flora, Neptune, Vesta, Ceres.

And of course

> it is itself the name of a Roman god.